# An exercise in Atiyah's book K-Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

[image]

This copy is from Atiyah's book K-Theory page 33, and it contains an exercise. I understand that real, quaternion bundle are orthogonal, symplectic bundle respectively. But I do not know how to figure out the converse statement. What is the exact meaning of this paragraph?